# Height of a $d$-ary heap of $n$-elements in terms of $n$ and $d$?

Tags: algorithms

I worked on this problem via the following approach:

- 1. $$n \le 1 + d + d_2 + \dots + d_h$$
  2. $$n \ge 1 + d + d_2 + \dots + d_{h-1} + 1$$

These two equations led me to the following range of $h$:

- $$\log_d\left(\frac{n(d-1)+1}{2}\right) \le h \le \log_d((n-1)(d-1)+1)$$

But I can’t figure out how to further deduce from this inequality so that $h = \Theta(\log_d n)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your last inequality,
$$\log_d\left(\frac{n(d-1)+1}{2}\right) \le h \le \log_d((n-1)(d-1)+1)$$
Now for all $n, d \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $n, d \ge 2$,
$$n\frac{d}{2} \le n(d - 1) \le n(d - 1) + 1$$
and
$$(n - 1)(d - 1) + 1 \le n(d - 1) + n = nd$$
Taking log on both inequalities,
$$\log_d\left(\frac{nd}{4}\right) \le \log_d\left(\frac{n(d-1)+1}{2}\right) \le h \le \log_d((n-1)(d-1)+1) \le \log_d(nd)$$
Forget the terms in the middle and apply the log laws,
$$\log_d n + \log_d d - \log_d 4 = \log_d\left(\frac{nd}{4}\right) \le h \le \log_d(nd) = \log_d n + \log_d d$$
Hence, 
$$h = \Omega(\log_d n + \log_d d - \log_d 4) = \Omega(\log_d n + 1 - \log_d 4) = \Omega(\log_d n)$$
and
$$h = \mathcal{O}(\log_d n + \log_d d) = \mathcal{O}(\log_d n + 1) = \mathcal{O}(\log_d n)$$
By definition, 
$$h = \Theta(\log_d n)$$